# The encoding is different in two device?

Tags: android, json

When i launch my application in Galaxy SII or Nexus S 
I obtain in have no problem with Nexus S but with Galaxy SII i got a problem of encoding ! (I got all the text of my application from a distant json file)

Comment: So what are we supposed to do now? Add more information/code/LogCat

Answer (score 3):

JSON is always encoded in some Unicode form.  There are two possibilities:

1. the JSON file is not in Unicode, if so, it's not valid: inform the owner
2. your application is decoding it incorrectly.

The [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) tells you exactly how to figure out which particular Unicode encoding has been used.  Examine the first four octets of the string and figure out the encoding from the following table.

```
       00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
       00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
       xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
       xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
       xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

This works because the first two characters of a JSON string are always from the ASCII character set (non ASCII characters are only allowed inside strings).